# Solidity dynamic arrays in memory: overflow bug

Tags: arrays, memory, overflow

I was trying to create a lottery smart contract that stores every tickets (ticket = address) that someone buys into into an array to later on select winners from it. Unfortunately I stumbled into an overflow error at line 16, I have looked up at the debugger but I can't understand why it goes into overflow. The first piece of code is a solution that I come up to after seeing many people using fixed arrays instead of dynamic ones but still it doesn't work. I just want to understand why it throws that error and how I can solve it. Thank you in advance for your help!

the error:

"error": "Failed to decode output: Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="toNumber", value="35408467139433450592217433187231851964531694900788300625387963629091585785856", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)"

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Lottery{

    address[] public s_players; //storage

    function enterLottery(uint _tickets) public payable returns (address[] memory) {
        uint lotteryCost = _tickets*250000000000000000;
        address sender = msg.sender;
        require(msg.value >= lotteryCost, 'Ticket cant be purchased');
        address[] memory _players = new address[](1000);
        _players = s_players;
        uint index = _players.length;
        for (uint x = 0; x < _tickets; x++){
            _players[index] = payable(sender); //.push() only storage arrays = use index
            index += 1;
        }
        s_players = _players;
        // Tickets as input, return players
        return s_players;
    }
}
```

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Lottery {

    address payable[] public s_players; //storage

    function enterLottery(uint _tickets) public payable returns (address payable[] memory) {
        uint lotteryCost = _tickets*500000000 gwei;
        require(msg.value >= lotteryCost, 'Ticket cant be purchased');
        address payable[] memory _players = s_players;
        uint length = _players.length;
        for (uint x = 0; x < _tickets; x = unsafe_inc(x)){
            _players[length] = payable(msg.sender); //.push() only storage arrays = use index
            length += 1;
        }
        s_players = _players;
        // Tickets as input, return players
        return s_players;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details how reproduce your error?

Comment: I got this explanation for the error on stack overflow: "The overflow came from the fact that your dynamic array was set to a static array value, and it lead to a number with 77 digits. In solidity the biggest possible number is 2^255 - 1, as that is how much 256 bits of information can store. (5.7896045e76)" The problem is that the code he submitted still uses a storage array which makes the function a problem to work with cause of gas.

If you copy and paste the code into remix IDE, compile it and deploy it once that you call the function the error will pop out, and you can debug the txn